# Simple Styling a Button in XAML WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I've been trying to style a button in XAML WPF but after a certain hours of searching I still couldn't find an easy and simple solution.

That's how I'll style my link `<a>Button</a>` in HTML & CSS:

```
a{   
    display: inline-block;    
    border-top: 1px solid #363636;   
    border-bottom: 1px solid #121212;  
    border-right: 1px solid #121212;  
    border-left: 1px solid #363636;  
    background: #282828;  
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;  
    width: 165px;  
    line-height: 25px;  
    font-size: 13px;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: #ebebeb;  
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #121212;  
}
```

P.S. Can't post images. You can see a button [here (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/a8bsh/1/).

Comment: And you want to apply a similar style in xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not familiar with all the CSS properties, but you can override it's `ControlTemplate` to be something like this:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Width="165">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#363636"/>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#363636"/>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#121212"/>
                                </Border.BorderBrush>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#121212"/>
                                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                               FontSize="13"
                                               Width="165"
                                               Padding="25,0,0,0">
                                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#ebebeb"/>
                                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
                                        <TextBlock.Background>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#282828"/>
                                        </TextBlock.Background>
                                        <TextBlock.Effect>
                                            <DropShadowEffect Color="#121212"/>
                                        </TextBlock.Effect>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

However this is a bit of a hack, but I think this is what you are looking for. If you want to do this right however, you should look into [creating your own decorator](http://www.wiredprairie.us/journal/2006/09/wpf_decorators_build_your_own.html).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. Different border color is my main problem.Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @Sandwich What is "border"? Are you refering the the different legs of the button?

Comment: Maybe. If you mean edges. My button is just a simple rectangle with different color of it border. I want to draw lines of different colors on the edges of the button.

Comment: @Sandwich Updated my answer with a more suitable solution. Hope this helps

Comment: I was trying to avoid tricky ways. WPF Decorators - I think that is solution what I was looking for. Thank you kindly.